# how to show feedback when using systemctl

Tags: systemd

When restarting services using init scripts, you can get a visual feedback (success or fail). 
When I use "systemctl restart ..." I don't get to see any feedback.

Is there a way to show whether a service was restarted correctly or not?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that "no feedback" actually means "everything ok". Anyway, you can explicitly test the status of a service with

```
 systemctl status <service>
```

Distributions might have equivalent commands. For example, in Debian I can also use

```
service <service> status
```

Comment: That's not the case, at least in Centos. It does not tell you the server failed to start for example. Yet, you can tell from logs or status. But I think @jorre is looking for immediate terminal feedback.